# Pass through exact unmatched parameter to child component

Tags: blazor, razor-components

I found out recently that blazor can pass through unmatched parameters to whatever element I want like this:

MyComponent.razor

```
<div @attributes=AdditionalAttributes />
@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

MyPage.razor

```
<MyComponent style="..." />
```

This works wonders.

But, what if I want to pass just some of these unmatched parameters to a nested component of `MyComponent`?

Would it look like this?

MyComponent.razor

```
<div @attributes=AdditionalAttributes>
    <MyOtherComponent @OneOfItsAttributes=AdditionalAttributes[theAttribute] />
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

MyPage.razor

```
<MyComponent style="..." theAttribute="..." />
```

Is there such a thing?
If so, does it work with `@bind-`?

A mechanism like this would greatly reduce code, so that if we are combining 2 or more components into one container component, we wouldn't have to copy-paste and bind all parameters from both components into that one container component.

### Edit

I've read [this article about cascading parameters](https://chrissainty.com/understanding-cascading-values-and-cascading-parameters/), and it looked like it could be the solution, but at the section *Updating Values* where writer asks

> But what if we wanted to trigger an update from a component deeper in the component tree that was declared in a different component?

is what interests me.

The solution that writer proposes is to create a service to manage these variables, though what I am creating isn't something that is persistent enought to be stored in a service.

What I mean by that:
Here's my component tree

- `DbInputSlider`

  - `MyInputSlider`

    - `MySlider`
    - `MyInputBase`

I believe you can see how I will be reusing all of these components and which one provides which functionality.

So my question is maybe more about efficiency, where I'd like to, with as least code as possible, and after my `DbInputSlider` loads a dictionary from database, send that dictionary down to `MyInputSlider` and then to `MySlider`, while `MyInputSlider` can still get `OnSave` event from `MySlider` so that he can hide `MySlider` and just show the selected value, and still propagate that event to `DbInputSlider` so that it can save the selected value to database.

I sware I tried to explain everything as short as possible.

Comment: Without seeing some code of what these components look like it's hard to answer this.  Is this an inheritance tree or does `DbInputSlider` contain a component called `MyInputSlider` and it contain two components `MySlider` and `MyInputBase`.   In general `DbInputSlider` shouldn't be loading data from a database, it should be loading it from a service.  And where does `Save` save the value to?

Comment: `DbInputSlider` contains `MyInputSlider` and `MyInputSlider` contains `MySlider` and `MyInputBase`. `DbInputSlider` does use service to get/save information from/to database. `DbInputSlider` saves info on focus out event (strange, but that's what I've decided on). If for example `DbInputSlider` would inherit from `MyInputSlider`, would I be able to add any additional html elements or css styles? If so, maybe that's how I'd make this work, as I would be skipping the intermediate parameters and events.